# Calculating CPU Usage from 'sar'

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

I started using Linux OS a while ago so, I am a beginner. I wanted to collect total CPU for a given process into a file with a given interval. For that reason I am using `sar` utility.

```
cpx@cpx-VirtualBox:~$ sar -u 1 4

Linux 4.4.0-142-generic (cpx-VirtualBox)        07/15/2019      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

10:28:25 PM     CPU     %user       %nice        %system    %iowait      %steal     %idle
10:28:26 PM     all      7.22        0.00        2.06        0.00        0.00       90.72
10:28:27 PM     all     10.10        0.00        3.03        0.00        0.00       86.87
10:28:28 PM     all      7.14        0.00        2.04        0.00        0.00       90.82
10:28:29 PM     all      7.00        0.00        2.00        0.00        0.00       91.00
```

In Windows, task manager shows overall CPU usage with user and kernel usage in the graph. So, I am unaware of other parameters and in Linux, it seems there's no easy way to see the total CPU.

So, What is the Total CPU here? Should I just do: `100 - idle% value` to get the total CPU Usage? Or, is it just %user + %system i.e. user time + kernel time?

Comment: why from sar? seems to much work ... why not use /proc/stat ? or from top? can you install software? "mpstat" from package "sysstat" is what was made for this question ;)

Comment: I found that proc/stat doesn't give real time CPU. Mpstat seems like sar. I am not using top because I want to log it every second so it seemed like sar has interval option to collect it.

Answer (score 1):

You need %user + %nice + %system for total CPU.

If %user gets close to 100% it might be because of you running "sar"; keep the intervals relative long.

- %iowait is time that the processor/processors are waiting **but it is only for a single CPU** So useless for multi cores.
- %steal is the percentage of time a virtual CPU waits for a real CPU

Comment: Why not do `100 - %idle`? Thanks. Are `%iowait` and `%steal` not relevant?

Comment: iowait is time that the processor/processors are waiting **but it is only for a single CPU** So useless for multi cores.  %steal is the percentage of time a virtual CPU waits for a real CPU %idle: the percentage of time the processor is idle **and is not waiting for I/O** If you don't want that latter you can use %idle

Comment: I see. So, if I add %user, %nice,  %system, and %idle. Will that give me a value of 100%? Or, do I need to add all the values in the row to get it?

Comment: Yes. If you count all the lines you will get 400 so you need to divide by 4 CPUs.

Comment: I see. In my example I have only one CPU :)